# Consequences of leaving masters program after dealing with unorthodox advisor

Tags: masters, advisor

I am a masters student in Computer Science at a high ranking university (top 20) in United States. I received my bachelors degree from this university as well. My GPA for both bachelor and master is above 3.9. I have finished all my course works and now I am just focusing on writing thesis. My thesis area is not directly related to CS so my advisor is not from CS department. We try to meet every week but during our yesterday's meeting, something unexpected happened.

**Conversation**:

- **Me**: Hi Professor X, I have this idea that is something original. Here are the
  reasons why it is an awesome idea and it can possibly have a huge
  impact with regards IoT. Here are the 5 page description on what this idea is, what are the advantages and disadvantages and why everyone
  should adopt this idea.
- **Professor X**: After 5 minutes. This idea is a: "piece of $hit. We
  cannot write a paper with this idea. It will be rejected immediately"... "only an
  idiot comes up with such a stupid idea".
- **Me**: But this idea is revolutionary ...
- **Professor X**: "Don't waste my time" ...
- **Me**: (calmly) I apologize if it was an irrelevant idea. I will try to do better next time.

This scenario has been repeated multiple time this semester and previous semester while working with this Professor.

**I come from a country that teachers in general are highly respected and we believe everything that teacher says or does is for benefit of a student**. I am not a person who will cry and get offended by this language. Fortunately or unfortunately, I have been bullied by my friends and siblings throughout my life and such a language doesn't trigger me. Instead, it motivates me to work harder.

In the end of meeting, I wanted to say to my advisor but I did not that a well known software engineering company offered me job (without me applying for the job) and I am not sure I should accept it or not, because I want to continue with my masters.

I had a conversation today with my family. They all live in rural area and they are all farmers. I am the only in my family who pursued college degree. I did not tell them what happened yesterday. But, **I am disappointed at myself for putting myself in such a situation. I am disappointed at myself and not at my advisor.**

**Question**: What are the consequences of leaving masters program and how in long term it will influence my chances of studying in Ph.D. program? my goal is to become a Professor.

Comment: You say that the conversation yesterday was "unexpected" but you also say that "[t]his scenario has been repeated multiple time this semester and previous semester while working with this Professor."  Something is fishy. We can't know what's going on, you should talk to a trusted third party.

Comment: You two are not interacting with each other in a healthy way.  I mean, your idea might indeed be a piece of ____, but that was no way to speak to a student.  On the other hand, your response was not helpful.  If you behave like a doormat, you are more likely to get treated like a doormat.  And then you displaced your disappointment in your advisor onto yourself -- this is not healthy.  I suppose it may be a reflection of the culture you grew up in.  But it's still not helpful.  So -- now what?  You and your advisor seem to be in a death grip, like when the floundering drowning person ...

Comment: ... grabs hold of the would-be rescuer, and they drown together in a death grip.  What you need to do is talk to the dean of graduate studies in your department.  Perhaps it would be helpful to switch advisors, if only temporarily.  You need to show your revolutionary idea to someone else, someone with some objectivity and the ability to let you know politely whether it is worth pursuing.